# How to solve native snappy library not available: SnappyCompressor has not been loaded?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, snappy, bigdata

I run wordcount by Mapreduce but occured a error . the native snappy library not available: SnappyCompressor has not been loaded. I think the snappy library not been loaded. however when I check the native library that the snappy library is ok .I don't konw how to solve it.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what operating system your hadoop distribution is installed. Usually pre build snappy compression is shipped with Hadoop for some os like Ubuntu,RHEL etc.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/NativeLibraries.html#Native_Hadoop_Library

If you are using other operating system you need to install/build snappy for that os and integrate it to your hadoop cluster by making config changes.
To enable snappy on cent os you can follow below url

http://www.ericlin.me/enabling-snappy%EF%BC%8Dcompression-in-hadoop-2-4-under-centos-6-3